# Does print statement in java effect any variables (without using increment)?

Tags: java, system.out

I was trying out the leetcode problem [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/diameter-of-binary-tree/description/)

the code i wrote is

```
public int toLeaf(TreeNode j){
        int ans=1;
        try{
            ans= Math.max(toLeaf(j.left),toLeaf(j.right))+1;
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        return ans;
    }
    public int diameterOfBinaryTree(TreeNode root) {
        return toLeaf(root);
    }
```

which gave me wrong answer but as soon as added a print statment i got correct answers on the sample testcases

```
public int toLeaf(TreeNode j){
        int ans=1;
        try{
            ans= Math.max(toLeaf(j.left),toLeaf(j.right))+1;
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        System.out.println(j.val+" "+ans);  //here
        return ans;
    }
    public int diameterOfBinaryTree(TreeNode root) {
        return toLeaf(root);
    }
```

what is the reason behind this?
[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eSiK.png)
[rejected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OvGY.png)

Comment: Do not catch exceptions without handle it

Comment: No, printing does not affect the value of variables. (unless your classes have a ***very*** weird `toString()` implementation, `int` certainly does not have that)

Comment: Regardless the logic you are trying to implement, this code is incorrect, as it should be throwing NPE, due to the fact that you are using recursion, however there is no stopping condition, in your code you are swallowing the exception.
And no priting doesn't affect the variables, unless you are doing on the fly assignment (e.g. `System.out.println((i+=2));`

Comment: The answer is simple: No. You did not include enough code to make a meaningful remark about what is causing what you're observing. But it isn't 'println changing variables'.

Comment: This code looks like a great puzzler for job interview .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printing is not the cause of the different behaviour but the access of `j.val` is.

If you had proper null-checks in your code, e.g. `if (j == null) { return 0; }` in the beginning of the method this would not happen.

In the first snippet if you call the method with `j = null` you get an NPE in the `try`, catch it, ignore it and then return 1. The caller will get the 1, add 1 and then `return 2`.

In the second snippet if you call the method with `j = null` you once again get an NPE in the try, ignore it, then continue to the `print` which raises another NPE which is then thrown from the method and the recursive caller will catch it and *not* perform the `ans = ... + 1` successfully but simply `return 1`.

Therefore you have a different behaviour between the two snippets. **But this is entirely unrelated to printing itself**.